# SSIS - Process failing with message : "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"

Tags: ssis

We have been running an SSIS package successfully in production now for 3 weeks, after 2 months of extensive testing.  Last night the package failed repeatedly with the error message :

*"Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"*

On one occasion it failed with message :

*"A buffer failed while allocating 10483456 bytes."*

Any ideas would be welcome!

Comment: Well, I've got to ask the obvious: (a) You have checked available storage space, right? (b) does this belong on Serverfault? [I don't know, I know nothing about SSIS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to many many times with packages scheduled through SQL Agent and I haven't been able to figure out why. Usually I would simply restart the server and then kick off the job again and it would work. I realize this isn't a solution but MSDN really doesn't offer any great explanations as to why this does occur.